# Adding minute amounts of different sound Convolved to a Mix....effect?

Tags: convolution-reverb

Hey,
I am looking for a way to make things unique.
I'm a firm believer that sounds all have an internal mechanism on our psyche through their timbre.

Would you think that by using several sounds and convolving them at a very low level output of the reverb, you would contribute the feeling associated with the particular sounds?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience with using various non-IRs as IRs in convolution reverbs, the effect has to be prepared well because it is odd / nonrealistic even in small doses, but definitely changes the emotional impact. For a while I was very interested in convolving human speech with bird calls, which does some very fascinating things.